# remove numbers from filenames in Mac OS X

Tags: regex, batch-rename

I have a directory full of files with names in this format (with numbers as the start of each filename):

```
102_file.txt
104_list.txt
242_another_file.txt
```

I would like to rename them as follows (i.e. removing the numbers):

```
file.txt
list.txt
another_file.txt
```

Can anyone suggest a way to do this (presumably from the terminal)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I assume you have the bash shell on your mac.

You can do it using the bash [parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html):

```
for name in *; do mv -v "$name" "${name#[0-9]*_}"; done
```

This will remove all digits up to the first `_`.

Note: this will overwrite files which end up having the same name.

Example:

```
$ ls -1
000_file0.txt
001_file1.txt
002_file1.txt
003_003_file3.txt

$ for name in *; do mv -v "$name" "${name#[0-9]*_}"; done
`000_file0.txt' -> `file0.txt'
`001_file1.txt' -> `file1.txt'
`002_file1.txt' -> `file1.txt'
`003_003_file3.txt' -> `003_file3.txt'
```

both `001_file1.txt` and `002_file1.txt` will be renamed to `file1.txt`. in this case the file `001_file1.txt` is overwriten by file `002_file1.txt`. which file will get overwriten depends on the ordering of the `*` glob. typically it is alphanumerical.

---

if the separating character is some other character then replace this character

```
for name in *; do mv -v "$name" "${name#[0-9]*_}"; done
                                              ^ this character
```

for example space

```
for name in *; do mv -v "$name" "${name#[0-9]* }"; done
                                              ^ space
```

Comment: This works for me where I have a space as opposed to an underscore e.g. `do mv -v "$name" "${name#[0-9]* }"; done ` It will prompt where it needs to overwrite any files. I there a way to force this to yes for all?

Comment: this might help you avoid prompt on overwrite https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/83496/how-to-copy-or-move-files-without-being-asked-to-overwrite

Comment: Thanks. Just reading up on shell expansion. e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43771388/how-to-remove-characters-in-filename-up-to-and-including-second-underscore Apparently if you can also use an -i flag on the mv command to avoid file getting overwritten if there are any name conflicts: