# Rename mp3 files to remove numeric extension

Tags: bash, mac, unix

I have a bunch of mp3 files that iTunes copied over adding a numeric extension, that I want to remove.  Is there a Mac bash command that will allow me to do that?  Here is what the directory looks like.  The files in question have 2 digits, and a space.

[image]

Comment: What is your research effort? What have you tried? Where are you stuck? "Gimme code" does not constitute a good question. My hint: [`vidir`](https://superuser.com/a/1503039/432690). You may get answers tailored to your specific request but in general I find the tool quite useful for renaming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a duplicate of:

[remove numbers from filenames in Mac OS X](https://superuser.com/questions/272237/remove-numbers-from-filenames-in-mac-os-x)

Modify the answer from there:

```
for name in *; do mv -v "$name" "${name#[0-9]* }"; done
```

I would first move 1 or 2 files into their own directory and try running that. If you get the desired results, then go into your main music directory and run it again.

Answer (score 0):

There is **rename** command in linux which you can use.

```
rename 's/^[0-9][0-9] //' *.mp3
```

The above command matched all the .mp3 files starting with two numbers followed by space. Check [this](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-rename-file/) link or **man** page for more details. I'm not sure if this command is available for mac.

Comment: The question is for Mac and *maybe* `rename` is well defined there (I cannot tell). In general in *nix there are [many similar programs](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/229230/108618) and `rename` in one distro may be different than `rename` in another distro.